# Log the authenticated user in the Postgres logs

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Use case - Need to log the authenticated user(not the database user) from the Python/Flask/Sqlalchemy in the Postgres logs.

At the moment I have enabled the Postgres logs with postgres.conf with the following format.

```
log_line_prefix = 'time=%t, %q db=%d, user=%u, ip=%h, app=%a'
```

This will log following format in the postgres.csv.

```
2021-11-17 09:56:18.856 GMT,"db_user_name","database_name",4962,"10.0.0.2:52068",6194d1c2.1362,16,"idle in transaction",2021-11-17 09:56:18 GMT,3/12392,0,LOG,00000,"statement: Query,,,,,,,,,"AppName"
```

I thought of following ways:

1. Concatenate username to application name dynamically.
2. Tried to find way to add some metadata(username) to the query.
3. Write a sql function to execute before an each query.

I tried to concatenate the username to app_name as following ways.

```
self.session.bind.url.query.update({'application_name': 'TEST_USERNAME'})
self.engine.url.query.update({'application_name': 'TEST_USERNAME'})
```

But this is not reflecting or updating the application name in the logs.

And also I tried to add some metadata on the query as well but it also not reflecting on logs.

For the sql function, I think it's an unnecessary overhead.

I would be curious to know is there anyone handle this use case or appreciate if someone can guide me to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use `application_name` for that.

You can either set that parameter in your connect string, or you can change the parameter any time by running

```
SET application_name = 'whatever';
```

or

```
SELECT set_config('application_name', 'whatever', FALSE);
```

Comment: Thank you. With this approach I need to update the application_name, execute my query, revert the application_name. What about the concurrency with this approach? Will it get mixed with when two users are interacting at the same time?

Comment: You can use `set_config(..., ...,TRUE)` to change the parameter only for the current transaction, and it gets reset automatically. concurrency is not an issue, because only one statement can run on one database session at any given time. But perhaps I misunderstand. With connection pooling, you'd have to use transactions.